# Any node.js packages that can emulate xbox controller input? Failing at wrapping the ScpDriverInterface dll :/

Tags: javascript, node.js, ffi

So I need to emulate a xbox controller with inputs comming from a nintendo switch.
I have the inputs but I can't find anyway to emulate xbox inputs :/

Anyone have some useful node.js packages I can try?

Another solution, but much more daunting, is to use the ScpDriverInterface and wrapp the dll using ffi-napi.
But it's a little out of my league. Unless someone wants to help me wrap it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out for anyone out there needing this.

I used the package vgen-xbox. works great!